# NetworkonMainThreadExecption with Twitter Timeline Feeds Example

Tags: java, android, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have tried to display twitter timeline user feeds with this [link](http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-twitter-timeline-feeds-example.html).  The different with my code is I try it in a Fragment class. In this code didn't need twitter4j.jar library, is it right ?? This is the code

```
public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {
public WhatsHotFragment() {
}

TextView tweetTextView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot,
            container, false);

    String twitterTimeline = getTwitterTimeline();
      try {
       String tweets = "";
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(twitterTimeline);
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        int j = i + 1;
        tweets += "Tweet #" + j + " \n";
        tweets += "Date:" + jsonObject.getString("created_at") + "\n";
        tweets += "Post:" + jsonObject.getString("text") + "\n\n";
       }
       tweetTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTextView);
       tweetTextView.setText(tweets);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

    return rootView;
}

 public String getTwitterTimeline() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
        "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/BBCNews.json?count=10&include_rts=1&callback=?");
      try {
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
       StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
       int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
       if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         builder.append(line);
        }
       } else {
        // Display couldn't obtain the data from twitter
       }
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return builder.toString();
     }
```

}

But i get error logcat:

```
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435): Process: com.tugasbesar.medantrain, PID: 1435
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.tugasbesar.medantrain.WhatsHotFragment.getTwitterTimeline(WhatsHotFragment.java:64)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.tugasbesar.medantrain.WhatsHotFragment.onCreateView(WhatsHotFragment.java:38)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-19 10:41:37.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

He say

> This project is tested in android 2.2 call the url in a separate
>   thread in android 3.0+ if a NetworkonMainThreadExecption occurs.

### But i have run it in android 4.0+. How to fix it ??

Updated code with AsyncTask class from @amit singh

```
public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {

public WhatsHotFragment() {
}

TextView tweetTextView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot,
            container, false);

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    tweetTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTextView);


    return rootView;
}

 public String getTwitterTimeline() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
        "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/BBCNews.json?count=10&include_rts=1&callback=?");
      try {
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
       StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
       int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
       if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         builder.append(line);
        }
       } else {
        // Display couldn't obtain the data from twitter
       }
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return builder.toString();
     }

 public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
 {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // Show progress dialog if you need...
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        String twitterTimeline = getTwitterTimeline();
        return twitterTimeline;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String twitterTimeline) 
    {
        try 
        {
            String tweets = "";
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(twitterTimeline);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int j = i + 1;
                tweets += "Tweet #" + j + " \n";
                tweets += "Date:" + jsonObject.getString("created_at") + "\n";
                tweets += "Post:" + jsonObject.getString("text") + "\n\n";

            }
            tweetTextView.setText(tweets);


        }   
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(twitterTimeline);
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: you can't work with network in `UI` thread on 3+, you need `AsyncTask` class to do this

Comment: What UI do you mean ?? Can you give me some code about AsynTask class ?

Comment: @user3212488 see my answer, add this class in your "WhatsHotFragment" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this-

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // Show progress dialog if you need...
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
    String twitterTimeline = getTwitterTimeline();
    return twitterTimeline;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String twitterTimeline) 
{
    try 
    {
        String tweets = "";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(twitterTimeline);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int j = i + 1;
            tweets += "Tweet #" + j + " \n";
            tweets += "Date:" + jsonObject.getString("created_at") + "\n";
            tweets += "Post:" + jsonObject.getString("text") + "\n\n";
        }
        tweetTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTextView);
        tweetTextView.setText(tweets);
    }   
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

and call this line from your onCreateView-

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

If you face any problm then you can ask.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. i want to vote your comment and your answer if i can :(

Comment: no problem buddy, you can vote afterwards when you get required points for this. ;)

Comment: tweetTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTextView);
Keep this line ahead of the asyncTask execution line.

Comment: no, just write it in this order in yout onCreateView()-

    tweetTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTextView);
new MyAsyncTask().execute();